# Android Emulator SQLite Database in Eclipse(Questoid)

Tags: android, sql, emulation

I have been doing a project where I have to get the values of a column and add them to get total of all. It is not working, so, according to my senior's suggestion from this article: http://www.tylerfrankenstein.com/browse-android-emulator-sqlite-database-eclipse#comment-64,I decided to install

http://www.questoid.com/Download.aspx

However, to make the problems worse, I can see all the icons except the icon that I need which is SQLite browser.
I have read forums and some suggest about storing the file the dropin folder but I couldn't see any dropin folder. Also I follow the installation guide of the product, my eclipse is Eclipse SDK 3.6.2 and my android emulator is 2.2 v.8:

> How To Install:
>
> Inside the downloaded .zip/.tar file there's a .jar file named
>   net.cellobject.sqlitexmlbrowser_1.2.0.jar.  Just copy this jar file
>   into the "plugins" folder of your eclipse installation directory, then
>   restart your eclipse.
>
> That's it.

I ran out of ideas so, Kindly help !

The error message is as shown in the picture.[image]

Failed to load Mainclass Manifest attribute from C:/Users/Thet Mon Aye/ eclipse/ etc etc

Comment: You made it further than I did. I cant even access their website to dl it. Is it available for dl somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

They (Questoid) have a [functioning site](http://www.questoid.com/Tools/CellObjectSQLiteXMLBrowser.aspx) now. You can get the latest version and support.

Comment: Hi Jason, where is the download link for the SQLite browser in that page? I only see one for the ADT download :(

Comment: thi site seems already abandoned (just a domain provider's placeholder). the plugin is dead?

Comment: @netalex Yes I have had nothing but problems with their website. I have given up on it and have just gone with SQLite data browser http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitedbrowser/